# VIM digraph not working

Tags: vim

I can't seem to get digraphs working for me in GVIM. 
[According to this site](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=443) (and the VIM wiki) I should be able to enter the mu character µ by being in insert mode then either Ctrl-Km* or Ctrl-Q956.

- When I try Ctrl-Km* I get *****
- When I try Ctrl-Q956 I get **ÿ**

It's driving me mad... I hate using u when I mean µ. I normally use Alt-0181 but that doesn't work in VIM either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help i_CTRL-V_digit` explains that the decimal number entry only works up to 255. To use that method, you'd have to enter the hexadecimal value `03BC`. The keystrokes therefore would be `<C-Q>u03bc`.

The digraph method should work, too. Do you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>, together, then release both, then type first `m`, then `*` individually?

Depending on the font, Vim may not be able to correctly display the character. You can use `ga` over it to verify its character codes.

Also, your encoding must support the character. Best use `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I don't know why the Ctrl-K m * doesn't work, but Ctrl-Q u0bc works great... thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help; do other digraphs work? If none do, ensure with `:verbose imap <C-k>` that the key isn't remapped.

Comment: I'm home now and vim seems to work a little differently in Ubuntu than it does on my win7 box at work. I'll have a tinker on Monday and see what's what. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to Ingo's answer, make sure that you (or one of your plugins) haven't remapped any keys. If you're using [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), for example, it remaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> in insert mode, so the first method you tried won't work. Since you're seeing a literal `*`, I suspect that's what's preventing that one from working.

To see if the key is mapped, and where it was mapped from, enter:

```
:verbose imap <C-k>
```

If it's mapped, you can remap it to something else, or just use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> solution.

For example, to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> perform the built-in digraph function, enter:

```
:inoremap <C-y> <C-k>
```

To make that permanent, put the line in your `~/.vimrc` (without the leading `:`).

Comment: In the case of UltiSnips, you can also change the triggers. I've put the following in my .vimrc: `let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"`, `let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"` and `let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"`. This way it doesn't hijack the default C-k, and the triggers are consistent.